# Apply `this` to variables in function auto

Tags: javascript

I want to parse function dynamic and apply `this` to variables in the function auto.

```
var functionContent = "console.log(v)";
var context = {v:'show some thing'}
(new Function(functionContent)).apply(context);
```

The parsed function will throw an error about can't found `v`. If I use `console.log(this.v)` instead, everything will be ok. But for better experience of end users, I don't want use `this` in `functionContext`. How can I do this?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: @jhpratt I want the code block above could run successfully.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you want to do in javascript terms is called binding.  You're setting the function scope for another function to an object.

```
var ctx  = {v:'show some thing'};
var newFunction = (new Function("console.log(this.v)")).bind(ctx);
newFunction();
```

I would also state, as the other answer does, that this is not a great thing.  new Function actually does use eval under the hood, it's basically just

```
eval("function(yourParams) { " + yourCode + "}")
```

Whether or not to get rid of it, well that's up to you.  If it's used on the broader internet and loads up some data people can edit... then yeah it may be an issue, but less so if it's just something small to play around with.

Comment: Is there some techs to handle user edit data form web and run it?

Comment: @lilei Generally any time you let a user write the code they want to execute, you open the system up to manipulation in ways you didn't consider.  It's not that you cannot do it, it's rather, that you generally ought not to.  If you need to, the way you have is the way that works, using ```new Function``` or ```eval```

Comment: Thank for your answer, actually that's the service of my company provided to our customers. I will do more works to enhance the security of the system.

Comment: Glad to help!  @lilei if possible I'd say check out https://developers.chrome.com/extensions/contentSecurityPolicy this may allow you to restrict usage of eval and Function by your consumers while allowing you to use it on page load.  If that doesn't work consider blacklisting statements like eval and new Function in what the user can submit.  The safest thing to do is whitelist what they can do, but it's also more time consuming than black listing what they can't